# Firefox updating React state continually although inputs don't change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox

I have two functions to handle mouse enter and leave as follows:

```
const handleMouseEnter = event => {
  const boundingClientRect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  setDelayHandler(
    setTimeout(() => {
      openDropDown(boundingClientRect, menuItem, subMenuItem);
    }, 200)
  );
};

const handleMouseLeave = () => {
  clearTimeout(delayHandler);
};
```

where `openDropDown` updates two pieces of state:

```
const openDropDown = (boundingClientRect, menuItem, subMenuItem) => {
  // Open dropdown only if it's an actual team
  if (subMenuItem.subMenu) {
    setSubMenuItem({ ...subMenuItem, parent: menuItem });
    setAnchorEl(boundingClientRect);
  } else {
    // Close any dropdown when you hover over the Add Team button
    closeDropDown();
  }
};
```

In few words, this code is supposed to open a submenu on mouse enter, close it on leave, and check if it should open another dropdown if the cursor is on a different menu. **It works fine in all browsers except Firefox, where the dropdown blinks (instead of staying open) as long as the mouse pointer is placed over the menu in question**.

Upon investigating, I noticed the following:

- The reason why the dropdown blinks is because Firefox is updating both pieces of state inside of `openDropDown` even when the inputs do not change.
- I tried other trivial actions inside the same function (like a `console.log`) and it does not follow the same pattern. It just executes the function once and then it's done. The same occurs if I perform a state update of a text variable. It only sets the state once.
- The above leads me to think that there's something wrong with how Firefox is interpreting the two state updates (`setSubMenuitem` and `setAnchorEl`). For your reference, the arguments to both functions (`subMenuItem`, `menuItem`, and `boundingClientRect`) are objects.

I tried to reproduce this problem in a code sandbox but was unable to get the same results, so it must be something with my application. However, I can't seem to be able to pinpoint exactly what's happening.

Any ideas or tips to correct this behavior will be more than welcome. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I cannot speak to your specific problem, but I've seen Firefox have a similar issue with `<input type='date' />`. It could just be the Browser?

Comment: @StackSlave My guess is it's the browser - in that case any ideas on how to prevent this behavior on Firefox?

Comment: The fact that you can't reproduce it in a sandbox is key. Work out why.

Comment: I couldn't do anything about it. Click on the box next to Start date:, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date). Once you see the date picker show up, blur out of it by pressing just off to the side in the same window. Click that same input again and it flickers. ????????????